# Lookup Filter "OR" Condition

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, lookup, lookup-filter

I would like to start using a filter on one of our lookup fields.  The lookup field is simply a lookup to a contact.  However, I need the filter to have an `OR` condition (e.g. only allow contacts from Account X **or** Account Y).

Is there any way I can allow multiple conditions?  Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use the filter logic.  You can click the Filter Logic link to allow you to add OR logic to your criteria

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the most intuitive placement (and different than how it works elsewhere in Salesforce), but, it does work!  Thanks

Comment: No prob.  Glad to help

Comment: Love the big red arrow! :)

Answer (score 5):

Below the list of "Filter Criteria" is a link that reads "Add Filter Logic..."  Once you click that, you'll have the option to create a complex filter logic such as `(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4) OR (5 AND 6) OR (7 AND 8)`

[image: Add Filter Logic...]